# Visual Studio Intellisense + Resharper throws ambigous symbol error when including the same header twice

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am using Resharper C++ with visual studio and I am getting an ambigous symbol error due to an apparent namespace clash. I get this error in Sd.cpp when, for example, I want to instantiate an enum Mode.

The enum class Mode is defined in Pins.hpp, which is included in Sd.hpp. However if I include Pins.hpp in Sd.ccp the ambigous symbol error pop ups. There is no problem compiling the project.

Could Resharper / Intellisense be not recognizing that Pins.hpp is the same file? The way `#pragma once` works is by the file path, so I don't know how that would happen.

I recently changed the include directories, so maybe this has something to do with the issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

Sd.hpp

```
#include "Pins.hpp"
```

Sd.cpp

```
#include "Pins.hpp"
Mode mode; //error here, Mode is underlined
```

Pins.hpp

```
enum class Mode : uint32_t
{
    AlternatePushPull  = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP,
};
```

EDIT1: Added code.
EDIT2: Renamed question to something more usefull

Comment: Show me the code.

Comment: Have you added an include guard to Pins.hpp? If the code compiles, please create an issue in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues?q=project:%20%7BReSharper%20C%2B%2B%7D and ReSharper team will try to help.

Comment: Yes, I am using `#pragma once`.

Comment: And #pragma once is defined in Reshaper? I don't remember it being in the standard.

Comment: From resharper 2016.2 changelog: ReSharper C++ will now warn you if a header file lacks an include guard and will provide a fix to automatically add a #pragma once directive. Therefore yes, @Surt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out ReSharper looks into the entire VS solution when linting, not solely the project. Since in my solution I had some project which included the same libraries, but from a different location. Therefore ReSharper could not resolve the names.

The solution was simple: make sure that all projects all include the same files.

Comment: I still don't understand why R++ would show an error. Could you please create a repro solution and the ReSharper team will take a look?